# Xstream not created in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, object, xstream

I'm debugging the unability to send serialized by XStream object via socket (it is created in dedicated thread, by the manual). And i've added debugging messages to send from client to server.

Client side

```
public class SocketClient implements Runnable {

static Socket client;
static Thread t;
static PrintWriter out;
static BufferedReader in;
static String strIn;

public static boolean CreateClientSocket(InetAddress ip) {
    try {
        client = new Socket();
        client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 9999), 0);
        t = new Thread(new SocketClient());
        t.start();
        return true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
}

public static void closeClient() {
    try {
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void sendClientPlayertoServer() {
    try {
        out.println("procedure start");
        XStream xs =new XStream();
        out.println("xs created");
        GameSave gs = new GameSave();
        out.println("gs created");
        ArrayList<PlayerSerialize> listps = new ArrayList<PlayerSerialize>();
        PlayerSerialize ps = new PlayerSerialize();
        out.println("ps created");
        ps.getPlayerData(Players.players.get(1));
        listps.add(ps);
        gs.playersSerialize = listps;
        gs.gamedate = Dateutils.gamedate;
        String s =xs.toXML(gs);
        out.println("gs converted");
        String[] ssplit = s.split("\n");
        out.println("clientplayertoserver");
        for (String spart : ssplit) {
            out.println(spart);
        }
        out.println("clientready");
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        Utils.debugWriteStringToFile(e.toString(), "sendclientexception");
    }
}

public static void sendClientReady() {
    out.println("clientready");
    out.flush();
}

public static void sendClientIsAlive() {
    out.println("clientisalive");
    out.flush();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        while ((strIn = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(strIn);
            if (strIn.contains("side")) {
                strIn = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(strIn);
                DialogMultiplayerStart.setSide(strIn);
            } else if (strIn.contains("startgame")) {
                DialogMainField.startNewGame(true, false, DialogMultiplayerStart.isFirstPlayerUSSR);
                DialogMultiplayerStart.callDispose();
            } else if (strIn.contains("serverprestige")) {
                strIn = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(strIn);
                Players.players.get(0).prestige = Integer.parseInt(strIn);
            } else if (strIn.contains("clientplayertoclient")) {
                strIn = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(strIn);
                XStream xs = new XStream();
                GameSave gs = (GameSave) xs.fromXML(strIn);
                Players.players.get(1).getPlayerSerializeData(gs.playersSerialize.get(0));
            } else if (strIn.contains("refreshgamefield")) {
                PanelNextTurn.refreshGameField();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Server side:

```
public class SocketServer implements Runnable {

static ServerSocket server;
static Socket client;
static Thread t;
static PrintWriter out;
static BufferedReader in;
static String strIn;

public static void CreateServerSocket() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(9999);
        t = new Thread(new SocketServer());
        t.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public static void closeServer() {
    try {
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void sendSide(String side) {
    out.println("side");
    out.println(side);
}

public static void sendStartGame() {
    out.println("startgame");
}

public static void sendServerIsAlive() {
    out.println("serverisalive");
}

public static void sendServerPrestige() {
    out.println("serverprestige");
    out.println(Players.players.get(0).prestige);
}

public static void sendRefreshField() {
    out.println("refreshgamefield");
}

public static void sendClientPlayertoClient() {
    XStream xs = new XStream();
    GameSave gs = new GameSave();
    ArrayList<PlayerSerialize> listps = new ArrayList<PlayerSerialize>();

    PlayerSerialize ps = new PlayerSerialize();
    ps.getPlayerData(Players.players.get(1));
    listps.add(ps);
    gs.playersSerialize = listps;
    gs.gamedate = Dateutils.gamedate;
    String s = xs.toXML(gs);
    Utils.debugWriteStringToFile(s, "clientplayertoclient");
    out.println("clientplayertoclient");
    out.println(s);
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        client = server.accept();
        DialogMultiplayerStart.updateAfterConnection();
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        out.println("test from server");

        while ((strIn = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(strIn);
            if (strIn.contains("clientplayertoserver")) {
                String s=new String();
                while(!(strIn=in.readLine()).contains("clientready")){
                    s=s+strIn;
                }
                XStream xs = new XStream();
                GameSave gs = (GameSave) xs.fromXML(s);
                Players.players.get(1).getPlayerSerializeData(gs.playersSerialize.get(0));
             PanelNextTurn.setClientReady();
            } else if (strIn.contains("clientisalive")) {
                DialogMainField.startNewGame(true, true, DialogMultiplayerStart.isFirstPlayerUSSR);
                DialogMultiplayerStart.callDispose();

            }
        }
        out.println("CYCLE ENDED!!!");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        out.println("caught error");
        Logger.getLogger(SocketServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Setting side (sendSide) and start game (sendStartGame) commands works great, checking that server and clients are alive after game data load - also works fine. But no way of sending client turn to server.

The problem is that server side receives only "procedure start" message and there is no file with logged error. Are there any limitations or problems of using XStream this way? What should I use as a different way to send object via socket?

Comment: Show how your server is reading the data. Also show how you are transfering the serialized data.

Comment: Your request is answered in the updated post.

Comment: you are using a bufferedwriter or bufferedreader? If yes, then you should also call `flush()` and `close()` on the outputstream and `flush()` on the inputstream.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is not related to XStream but on how you are writing the data between Client and Server.

I created a small Sample for you to run. It is using mostly your server code and client code. 
I guessed a few implementations you have done and added flushes and close of streams / socket to the code.

Run the code and see how the data is being transferred from client to the server. Should be enough to get you going from where you are stuck.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class ClientServerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread server = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Server();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        server.start();
        Client.sendClientPlayertoServer();
    }

    static class PlayerData {

        private List<Player> listps;
        private Date gameDate;

        public PlayerData(List<Player> listps) {
            this.gameDate = new Date();
            this.listps = listps;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String state = "Game from " + gameDate + " " + listps.size()
                    + " Players.\n";
            for (Player p : listps) {
                state += p.toString();
            }
            return state;
        }

    }

    static class Player {
        private String name;

        public Player(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Player " + name + "\n";
        }
    }

    static class Server {
        Server() throws IOException {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
            Socket s;
            while ((s = serverSocket.accept()) != null) {
                readFromClient(s);
            }
        }

        private void readFromClient(Socket sock) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    sock.getInputStream()));
            String strIn;
            while ((strIn = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strIn);
                if (strIn.contains("clientplayertoserver")) {
                    String s = new String();
                    while (!(strIn = in.readLine()).contains("clientready")) {
                        s = s + strIn;
                    }
                    XStream xs = new XStream();
                    PlayerData gs = (PlayerData) xs.fromXML(s);
                    System.out.println("***Server received playerData:\n" + gs);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Client {
        public static void sendClientPlayertoServer() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        socket.getOutputStream()));
                out.println("procedure start");
                XStream xs = new XStream();
                out.println("xs created");
                out.println("gs created");
                List<Player> listps = new ArrayList<Player>();
                Player ps = new Player("Someone");
                out.println("ps created");
                listps.add(ps);
                PlayerData gs = new PlayerData(listps);

                String s = xs.toXML(gs);
                out.println("gs converted");
                String[] ssplit = s.split("\n");
                out.println("clientplayertoserver");
                for (String spart : ssplit) {
                    out.println(spart);
                }
                out.println("clientready");
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                socket.close();

                System.out.println("+++ Client send this object:\n" + gs);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output of that example:

```
procedure start
xs created
gs created
ps created
gs converted
clientplayertoserver
+++ Client send this object:
Game from Mon Jan 13 19:44:06 CET 2014 1 Players.
Player Someone

***Server received playerData:
Game from Mon Jan 13 19:44:06 CET 2014 1 Players.
Player Someone
```

The output is mostly from your code. The program will not terminate as the ServerSocket will keep listening for more clients, exception handling is also missing.
However this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Please check question update - I've added flush (still no effect :( ), and copied the full client/server code.